# How to find $\theta$

Tags: trigonometry

If $0\leq\theta\leq360$, and:
$$\cos(\theta-35.54)=\frac{8}{\sqrt{74}}$$

How to find $\theta$? Can anyone give me some hints?

Comment: If you're working in degrees, please state that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Invert the cosine function to give:

$$\theta - 35.54^o = \cos^{-1}\frac{8}{\sqrt{74}}$$
which has a principal value of $21.6^o$. Can you find the other values in the range? Be careful, because if
$$0<\theta<360^o$$ then $$0 - 35.54^o<\theta - 35.54^o<360 - 35.54^o$$ i.e. $$-35.54^o<\theta - 35.54^o<326.46^o$$ so you are looking for inverse cosines between $-35.54^o$ and $326.46^o$.

Then add $35.54^o$ to each side, for every value you found above to get $\theta$

Comment: Is 338.43 another value?

Comment: it is another, yes.

Comment: When it adds with $35.54$. It's out of range. So should I write it out?

Comment: it's worth keeping it in the bulk of your solution but leaving it out of your final answer. see edit